# Onload event not working, but function works with an onclick event javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a snippet here that should show weather or not java is enabled. I had it set to run via onclick of a button, but I want to instead use an onload event in a P element to show the results.

the issue I am having is I get no results shown when i have set to an onload event, but it I create a button and use an onclick event it works.

what could be the issue here?

**html**

```
<p><strong>Display weather browser has java enabled.</strong></p>
<p id="javaAnswer" onload="checkJava()"></p>
```

**javascript**

```
    function checkJava() {
        var x = "Java Enabled: " + navigator.javaEnabled();
        document.getElementById("javaAnswer").innerHTML = x;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The onload event in attached to the following tags exclusively:
`<body>`, `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input type="image">`, `<link>`, `<script>`, `<style>`.

It does not apply for any other tag.

if you insist to execute the script after the `<p>` element insert a new script tag immediately after the `<p>` tag.

```
<script>
    checkJava();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it.

```js
function checkJava() {
  var x = "Java Enabled: " + navigator.javaEnabled();
  document.getElementById("javaAnswer").innerHTML += x;
}
```

```html
<body onload="checkJava()">
<p><strong>Display weather browser has java enabled.</strong></p>
<p id="javaAnswer"></p>
</body>
```